# How does Spring's @RequestMapping work?

Tags: java, spring, aop

As you know `@RequestMapping` get used to intercept a `HttpServletRequest`.

I want to know how `@Controller @RequestMapping` together can bind a request coming from a client to a specific method inside a java class ?

I want to write a similar java application to do the same functionality, Imagine We have a class like this:

```
@Actor
public class JavaForever {

  @Department(value="IT")
  public void departmentIT(){...}

  @Department(value="Physic")
  public void departmentPhysic(){...}
}
```

And a StudentBean class :

```
public class StudentBean {

    private String department;
    private Integer age;
    //Other class variable
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

and finally we have a Test class like this:

```
public class TestApplication {
   //getStudentFromDatabaseMethod() implementation here

   public static void main(String[] agrs){
     List<StudentBean> allStudents = new TestApplication().getStudentFromDatabaseMethod();
   //other codes
   }
}
```

As you see `getStudentFromDatabaseMethod()` returns `List< StudentBean>`, now the question is how we can force this method to get intercept with our `@Department` annotation which resides in `JavaForever` class `before` it returns any value ...

how we can do this ???

Comment: This is way too broad. Read the source code. Start at the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` class.

Comment: Spring does not use AOP for its `@Controller` handler methods.

Comment: I already look at that class but It has lots of additional aspects that makes too much confusion ...

Comment: To answer your question you need to understand and explain each thing that happens in that class and others, ie. too broad. Spring's MVC stack is no joke.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis did you have written any code in this matter before ???

Comment: I have. It seems in this case you might want to use AOP, but again that is too broad if you don't already know what AOP is and how Spring implements it. I recommend you go read the documentation and some tutorials.

Comment: If you have a specific issue about AOP, we can help, but there's too much to cover here.

Comment: I understand, no I don't have. I think, I have to go over AOP and Spring Integration with AOP in depth because I needs it too much. thank you

Comment: @Mehdi: What exactly do you mean by AOP ? Just reading annotations from classes/fields/methods has nothing to do with AOP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a broad overview

1. You identify the classes for Spring to search (for annotations).
2. Spring finds your @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations.
3. Spring builds a map of the URL values from the @RequestMapping annotations.
4. At runtime, when a request is received by Spring, it searches the map for the
    URL.  When it finds the URL, it calls the method that is marked with the
    @RequestMapping.

Summary:

- Annotations don't *do* anything.  They are markers for other classes that *do* stuff.

Start by reading an [Annotation Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/).
You will need to scan your classes (during startup) for your annotations (using reflection) then handle them appropriately.